# Invalid cross thread access

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am having this Model class where I am using `DataContract` to deserialize data received from server. So it has these two fields `Data` and `DataColor` where `Data` is being sent from server and `DataColor` is derived from it using some logic.

**ModelClass.cs**

```
    private double _data;
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public double Data
    {
        get { return this._data; }
        set
        {
            SetField(ref _data, value, "Data");
            this.DataColor = Util1.GetColorFromData(value);
        }
    }

    private SolidColorBrush _dataColor;
    public SolidColorBrush DataColor
    {
        get { return this._dataColor; }
        set { SetField(ref _dataColor, value, "DataColor"); }
    }
```

To set `DataColor` I am calling one of my Util1 class function.

**Util1.cs**

```
    public static SolidColorBrush GetColorFromData(double data)
    {
        // apply some logic to get hexColor from data
        return Util2.GetSolidColorFromHex(string hexColor);
    }
```

which in turn calls another class' Util2 function to convert `hexColor` to `SolidColorBrush`

**Util2.cs**

```
    GetSolidColorFromHex(string hexColor)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(
            Color.FromArgb(
                255,
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16)
            ));
    }
```

Now i don't have even the slightest idea why am I getting this `Invalid cross thread access` error in Util2.cs when I am trying to create `SolidColorBrush` object. I am not trying to change any UI object here.

I thought of using `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` here, but since I am returning values from function here, can't use Dispatcher I think.

I need to know why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?

I have wasted a lot of time on this and have tried to move `GetSolidColorFromHex` from `Util2` to `Util1`. Still no success.

Also isn't there some general way to avoid `Invalid cross thread` by passing some context or something else maybe.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although you're not trying to alter UI properties, a `SolidColorBrush` can only be instantiated on the UI thread.

You could do the creation on the UI thread to create a private variable of the brush, then return it.

**Edit:**

Without being at a PC to confirm, I believe something like this would work:

```
GetSolidColorFromHex(string hexColor)
{
    SolidColorBrush brush;
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        () => brush = new SolidColorBrush(
            Color.FromArgb(
                255,
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16)
        )));

    return brush;
}
```

Comment: Oh. But isn't there any other alternative. What I get from your answer is I should move the logic of Util1 and Util2 to a UI thread like MainPage.xaml.cs and call it from ModelClass.cs. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I find this pretty surprising. Afaik objects are supposed to be instanciable from other threads, frozen, and then sent to the thread where they will be used (this works for frozen images). Anyway can't you just work with a mere Color, rather than a brush? Or maybe you can create a second dispatcher on your other thread? I guess this would work.

Comment: I've come across a couple of objects that require UI thread access. For example, client-side contexts used in RIA Services with Silverlight, by default, need to be constructed on the UI thread.

Comment: @Joeb454 Your code won't work. I have tried it earlier but it will give an error as it will first return the non initiated brush object and then will execute dispatcher code.

Comment: @VictorVictis I will check if using Color will fit it my case. Thanks